# Scraping A Webpage With JSOUP and Given An SSL Error. Is This A Site Specific Issue? (JSOUP Works On Other Websites)

Tags: java, ssl, web-scraping, jsoup

Scraping A Webpage With JSOUP and Given An SSL Error. Is This A Site Specific Issue? (JSOUP Works On Other Websites)

I'm trying to run a scrape, I run scrapes like this all the time, but this one failed.
Normally I use jsoup to connect to a webpage, and then grab what I want on the page. This one appears to be trying to do an ssl handshake or something and failing.

I found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ) with a similar issue, but, I think the op is having that issue on all jsoup scrapes, where mine is specific to this one website.
https://www.strack.de/de/shop/?idm=1162&d=1&idmp=94&spb=MTQ7NzQ7MTI0OzEyMzY7
I have tried multiple pages on this site and all have the same issue. However, all other sites that I have tried don't have this issue at all and scrape normally.

I tried installing the latest version of java and restarting the pc, this didn't lead to the ssl connecting successfully. I also tried going onto Firefox and downloading the certification. That didn't seem to have the same pathway as described in the answer.

> "more info" > "security" > "show certificate" > "details" > "export.."

I think this issue might be caused by a separate problem as the scraper works just fine on other websites. This is why I created this as a separate question as opposed to a comment on that one.

Here is what happened when I tried to download the cert.
Instead of show certificate there is a view certificate, and it doesn't have the details option nor an export option.
[Trying to get the .cert file, no prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjccU.png)

Am I doing something wrong that is prompting a handshake or is this some sort of functionality that disallows scraping on this website? I tried to scrape the pricing off of this webpage:
https://www.strack.de/de/shop/?idm=1162&d=1&idmp=94&spb=MTQ7NzQ7MTI0OzEyMzY7

I used JSOUP to try to scrape this page.
It gave me an error. When I googled it, it seems to be an error that people get when trying to connect to servers.

It gave me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)     at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)  at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)  at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)     at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)   at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)    at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
> at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
> at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
> at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
> at
> org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:732)
> at
> org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:707)
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:297)
> at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:286)     at
> scrapetestforstack.de.ScrapeTestForStackDe.main(ScrapeTestForStackDe.java:81)
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
> building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
> at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
> at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)    at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
> ... 15 more Caused by:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
> at
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
> at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
> at
> sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
> ... 21 more
> C:\Users\LeonardDME\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
> Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Here is the code that I am trying to do.

---

//Phase 3 Scrape The URL for Urls
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

```
   title = doc.title();
                    
         TitleFixer = title.replaceAll(" ", "");
         title = TitleFixer.replaceAll("|", "");
         TitleFixer = title.replaceAll("|", "");
        title = TitleFixer.replaceAll(";", "");
   
  //Set file writing stuff 1
            GimmeAName = ("C:\\Users\\LeonardDME\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ScrapeTestForStackDe\\Urls\\" + title + ".csv");    
    File f = new File(GimmeAName);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw);    
            StuffToWrite = URLArray[counter];
            // fetch the document over HTTP               
                 Elements spangrabbers = doc.getElementsByClass("art_orginal_preis142790");
                   for (Element spangrab : spangrabbers)
        {
        //System.out.println("New Span: ");
        //System.out.println(spangrab);
        holder2 = spangrab.text();
        //System.out.println(holder2);
        SpanHolderArray[SpanHolderCounter] = holder2;
        SpanHolderCounter++;
        }
            // get all links in page
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {
                // get the value from the href attribute
                checker = link.attr("href");
                if (checker.contains("http"))
                {
                }
                else if(checker.contains("javascript"))
                {
                }
                else if(checker.contains("style"))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    counter++;

                    if(LinkContorter == null && LinkContorter.isEmpty())
                    {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(LinkContorter);
                        out.print(LinkContorter);
                        out.print(",");
                        out.print("\n");
                        //Flush the output to the file
                        out.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(counter);
        //Close the Print Writer
       out.close();       
       //Close the File Writer
       fw.close();
```

---

Is it possible that a few of you could try to scrape this site, and see if you get the same result as me? I suspect that there might be some safegaurd against scraping, but, I don't want to abandon the task unless I know that to be the case for sure. I also used to scrape this same website a few months ago in February or March without an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although as Firefox shows the cert used by this server does validate using the intermediate CA `Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA` and root CA `USERTrust RSA Certification Authority`, the server sends only the leaf cert and not the intermediate 'chain' cert as required by standards.

You can see this by looking at the [SSLLabs test report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.strack.de); notice the orange warning in the summary [image: SSLLabs summary] and this near the bottom of the cert details box [image: SSLLabs detail]. Alternatively if you have (or get) OpenSSL `openssl s_client -connect www.strack.de:443 -showcerts` (many servers today require SNI and for OpenSSL below 1.1.1 to send SNI you need to add `-servername $host` but not *this* server), or since you have Java `keytool -printcert -sslserver www.strack.de`.

Omitting the required chain cert(s) is a common mistake by server admins who don't bother reading documentation, because if they only test with a browser or two they don't notice the mistake -- browsers frequently can work-around the missing chain cert(s), but most other software, including Java, either cannot or not by default. It is unlikely to be intended as a deliberate anti-scraping measure since it is easily bypassed, see next, but it does suggest the server admin doesn't have an actual goal or interest to *support* or *assist* scraping.

Instead of ignoring *all* cert problems as [suggested by Krystian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68734651/2868801) you can fix this by obtaining the chain cert -- e.g. by exporting from Firefox or by fetching the caIssuer link in the cert `http://crt.sectigo.com/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt` (shown in the SSLLabs report, or the `keytool -printcert` decode, or if you run the `openssl s_client` output into `openssl x509 -noout -text`) -- and adding it to your truststore (by default the file `$JREDIR/lib/security/cacerts` or `jssecacerts` unless you change it with a sysprop or code).

(added) **Re Firefox**, you already found that the UI has changed slightly in the years since the Q you linked: you now click on the padlock, then the right-arrow, More Information, View Certificate. To export a specific cert, click the tab for "Sectigo RSA ..." and scroll about halfway down to this:
[image: Firefox cert info]
then click "PEM(cert)" and save somewhere appropriate.

You could also report this problem to the site admin or owner(s). Whether they will care about you or non-browser access in general I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not sending any sensitive data you can cheat a little and configure your own TrustManger to accept everything.

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }
} };

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

Now it will be used for EVERY connection so it's not recommended. Instead you can comment out the last line and make jsoup use it only for a single connection by specifying SSLSocketFactory like this:

```
// HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()); // not needed anymore
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                    .sslSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory())
                    .get();
```